# How do I seamlessly implement Google Tag Manager to a site that already has GA and Search Console?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, migration, data, tag-manager

We have a website with decent traffic and have been able to generate business from it. Currently, we have Google Analytics and Search Console and are getting data and these two are also linked. My CEO has been told by someone that we need to implement Tag Manager and move to the "next level".

I have no experience in doing this and I am very scared this can back fire and we can lose all data. Please can someone help?! If not anything, someone who can at least help with a "how to" guide or even some practical do's and don'ts?

Answer (score 2):

Your CEO is right, Google Tag Manager is definitely the way forward and it offers so much more than Google Analytics.

The first step is to add the Google Tag Manager container snippet to your site. This is done in two parts. The first section is added to the  tag and the second section is added to the  tag. Full details are explained here https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart. You get your GTM ID by setting up an account in Google Tag Manager (similar to the UA code in Google Analytics).

One of the best things about tag manager is that you can set up tags and test that they are firing in 'preview and debug' mode before publishing. Therefore, when you set up your Google Analytics tag, ensure that it works across all pages on the site. Once you are happy with this, you can remove your Google Analytics tag and publish  Google Tag Manager. That way you will not lose any data.